# SVG viewBox - Scaling in 2 directions

Tags: html, svg

I have the following nested elements:

```
<div>
<svg viewBox='0 0 240 60' preserveAspectRatio='xMidYMid meet'>
<rect width='240' height='60'></rect>
</svg>
</div>
```

I use `viewBox` to enable the SVG to fill the whole `div` container. BUT I want it to scale in two directions. So it can fill both of the following set of sizes for the `div` :

`height` = 120 , `width` = 480
`height` = 120 , `width` = 700

So it scales if both height and width scale OR if only width scales.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself that you can show us?

Comment: Right now I use the same code as in the question, but it only does 1 direction scaling. For the other one : no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow SVG to scale in both directions (and loosing aspect ratio) you have to use `preserveAspectRatio='none'`.